# Playing aac file with javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

Attempting to play a aac file with javafx

error is

error MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
version: 8.0.5-b13

code http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7303423/

Comment: Have you tried to create the MediaPlayer in a proper JavaFX application? Maybe the JavaFX platform has to be initialized first.

Comment: it works fine for playing static mp3' files but won't even play a local aac file

Comment: still, have you tried it with a proper JavaFX application?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by that?,

Comment: You're application doesn't extend javafx.application.Application. It creates a JFXPanel but does nothing with it? I suggest to follow the tutorial and see if you get the same issue: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm#JFXMD101

Comment: Still getting the same error when extending applicaiton, http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7322173/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, I connot spot the problem, but I can give you some suggestions:

- Try to access that URL with another existing player. Does it work?
- Download the AAC file and store it locally. Do you get the same error if you load the file from local disk.
- If you think it's a bug, please file the issue here: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com

Comment: After taking a poke through the jfx codebase it seems they only support aac if its embedded in a mp4 container, and not standalone

Comment: Then please file an enhancement request. And maybe also a patch?